# Mixing SRAM X01 and Apex components

Tags: sram

I have a bike with an SRAM X01 rear mech, and SRAM Guide Hydraulic disk brakes.

The bike has flat bars, but I'd like to swap them for a Salsa Woodchipper, which means swapping the shifters and brake handles.

Does anyone know if one can use an SRAM Apex shifter to control an X01 rear mech and Guide disks?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean the sram apex 1X 11 speed hydraulic?

Comment: @Rider_X yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRAM 11 speed road and mountain shifters and and rear derailers are not cross compatible. They work on different actuation ratios. A Jtek Shiftmate 9 can be used to convert them in the road shifter on mountain derailer direction.

SRAM says there is no compatibility between road and mountain hydraulic brakes. I believe they're probably right because the road levers push way less fluid, but I haven't actually tried it.